# Can't install Plotly in Scala

Tags: scala, plotly

I've started to learn Scala recently for machine learning purpose and i need plotly to draw my plots.
The fact is after following all installation 
steps on their site i get this error :

```
sbt:DAY_01> run
[info] Updating ...
[warn]  module not found: co.theasi#plotly_2.12;0.2.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/lucasclerisse/.ivy2/local/co.theasi/plotly_2.12/0.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/co/theasi/plotly_2.12/0.2.0/plotly_2.12-0.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/lucasclerisse/.sbt/preloaded/co.theasi/plotly_2.12/0.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/lucasclerisse/.sbt/preloaded/co/theasi/plotly_2.12/0.2.0/plotly_2.12-0.2.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: co.theasi#plotly_2.12;0.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      co.theasi:plotly_2.12:0.2.0 (/Users/lucasclerisse/Documents/Ecole/Piscine_IA_POC/DAY_01/build.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]        +- default:day_01_2.12:1.1.0
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: co.theasi#plotly_2.12;0.2.0: not found
```

Here is my sbt.build :

```
name := "DAY_01"

version := "1.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "co.theasi" %% "plotly" % "0.2.0"
```

I tried to downgrade my sbt version and another ploty version, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the exact library dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "co.theasi" % "plotly_2.11" % "0.2.0"
```

in your code sbt is trying to look for plotly dependency for scala version 2.12, which I guess is not available. As while going through there documentation, it looks that the latest version supports scala 2.11.

You can check here: [click](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22co.theasi%22%20AND%20a%3A%22plotly_2.11%22)

Comment: It worked by downgrading the version of scala used for the project. Thanks for your help.